# remove wrapping div and leave all sub-divs intact?

Tags: jquery

I have one wrapper div with several sub-divs inside and tags inside those sub-divs as well.  I want to remove the wrapper div.  I have considered JQuery's unwrap, but it appears as though I need to specify the child divs to tell Jquery what to unwrap.  Will this work if there are several children?

So, the code looks like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="innerDiv1"></div>
  <div id="innerDiv2"></div>
  <div id="innerDiv3"></div>
</div>
```

Any help, as always, is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method will work fine (you can select any of/any number of the siblings):

```
$("#innerDiv1").unwrap();
```

From the docs (emphasis added):

> The matched elements (**and their siblings, if any**) replace their
>   parents within the DOM structure.

Comment: Thanks @James Allardice.  Even though I checked the JQuery docs, I somehow missed the "and their siblings" part.  Getting a little bleary eyed I guess.

Answer (score 7):

To add on to @james

You can do something like this

```
var innerDivs = $("#wrapper").html();
$("#wrapper").remove();
$("body").append(innerDivs);​ // you will need to change this to append to whatever element you like
```

jsfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/dAZ9D/

Comment: You could do this, but you would lose any event handlers bound to the children of `#wrapper` because the elements are removed from the DOM completely and then added again. Using the `unwrap` method will preserve those event handlers as elements are never removed from the DOM.

Comment: yes thats right james but he doesn't specificly asked whether to maintain even handler or not. Thats why I said to "add on to James answer" :) Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be to use `.replaceWith()` in conjunction with `.html()`:

```
jQuery('#wrapper').each(function () {
    var t = jQuery(this);
    t.replaceWith(t.html());
});
```

Comment: Can also do like this in latest Jquery as in 2019: `$(this).replaceWith($(this).html());`

Answer (score 1):

```
function unwrap(el){
    var parent = el.parentNode; // get the element's parent node
    while (el.firstChild){
        parent.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el); // move all children out of the element
    }
    parent.removeChild(el); // remove the empty element
}
```

The code is straight forward and much faster than the corresponding jQuery's method $.unwrap().

Source: https://plainjs.com/javascript/manipulation/unwrap-a-dom-element-35/