# Removing a wrapping element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have:

```
<a href=''>
    <div>hello</div>
</a>
```

I want to remove the A element so to obtain:

```
<div>hello</div>
```

Can this be done in jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386544/remove-wrapping-div-and-leave-all-sub-divs-intact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.unwrap()` method removes the element's parent.

```
$('div').unwrap();
```

Comment: why posting already posted answer ?

Answer (score 5):

Use [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

```
$('div').unwrap();
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EqNnB/)

Answer (score 2):

use the unwrap() of jquery http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

```
$('div').unwrap();
```