# How to remove wrapper of multiple elements without jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of elements and want to remove its container wrapper in Javascript.

I've researched around ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386544/remove-wrapping-div-and-leave-all-sub-divs-intact), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580292/removing-wrapper-div-without-jquery-raw-javascript), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261197/how-can-i-remove-wrapper-parent-without-removing-the-child)) but I need a solution that 1) doesn't involve jQuery. 2) and can work on multiple elements.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="global-container stacked">
    <article class="global"></article>
    <article class="global"></article>
</div>
```

**I've tried:**

```
var globalArticles = document.getElementsByClassName('global');
globalArticles.outerHTML = globalArticles.innerHTML;
```

But that doesn't work. How would one go about removing the wrapper from all `article.global`?

Comment: Before you remove the `div` element, you'll need to move `article`s into the `div`'s parent.

Comment: an element cannot remove itself. the parent can remove a child. find `global` elements and put them inside the parent. then remove the container. http://stackoverflow.com/a/843681/1536309

Comment: Which wrapper are you trying to remove? Your code would remove `<article>` wrappers, do you want to remove `<div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create your own `unwrap()` method, something like this

```
function unwrap(elems) {
    elems = 'length' in elems ? elems : [elems];
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var elem        = elems[i];
        var parent      = elem.parentNode;
        var grandparent = parent.parentNode;

        grandparent.insertBefore(elem, parent);

        if (parent.children.length === 0) 
            grandparent.removeChild(parent);
    }
}

var globalArticles = document.getElementsByClassName('global');    

unwrap(globalArticles);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.innerHTML`, `.removeChild()`, `.insertAdjacentHTML()`

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".global-container");
var html = container.innerHTML; // store `html` of `container`
container.parentElement.removeChild(container); // remove `container`
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html); // append `html`
```

```html
<div class="global-container stacked">
    <article class="global">1</article>
    <article class="global">2</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var globalArticle = document.getElementsByClassName('global')[0];
if (globalArticle) {
    globalArticle.parentElement.outerHTML = globalArticle.parentElement.innerHTML;
}
```